# Jquery submit dont set values on inputs

Tags: jquery, submit

i have the this form:

```
<form id="segform" action="TestServlet" method="POST" >
  <div id="actives" class="rounded-corners">
    <div class="column">                        
     <div class="portlet"><a href="#">link1</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="inactives" class="rounded-corners">
    <div class="column">
     <div class="portlet"><a href="#">link2</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="ffactives" value="foovalue" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ffinactives" value="foovalue" />
  <input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

I need when the form was submitted the content of links being set into input:

ffactives = "link1" instead of "foovalue"
ffinactives = "link2" instead of "foovalue"

i use now the jquery code:

```
$('#segform').submit(function(){
  var act = $('#actives div.column div.portlet a').text();
  var inact = $('#inactives div.column div.portlet a').text();
  $('input[name=ffactives]').val(act);
  $('input[name=ffinactives]').val(inact);
  return true;
});
```

But when i receive the inputs the values was not changed.
i aspect ffactives = "link1" and ffinactives = "link2" , but i receive ffactives = "foovalue" and ffinactives = "foovalue"

Whats wrong

Comment: I just put together a test with that exact code and it worked for me (in Chrome anyway). I hope someone answers this question, because I'm interested to find out why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have works at face value, [you can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BZKCX/), a few things to check:

- Is this running in a [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler? e.g. your code should be wrapped in
  `$(function() { /* current code */ });` so that `$('#segform')` doesn't run until the `<form>` is in the DOM and ready to be found (otherwise it hooks a `submit` handler up to 0 elements.
- Are you getting any JavaScript errors?  If any occur before your code runs, the `submit` handler wouldn't be bound, and you'get get default submission behavior...which is what you're seeing.

Comment: SO thankful Craver. the problem was solved with document ready.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your JS is not running properly.  Try this version of your submit handler

```
$('#segform').submit(function(event){
  var act = $('#actives div.column div.portlet a').text();
  var inact = $('#inactives div.column div.portlet a').text();
  $('input[name=ffactives]').val(act);
  $('input[name=ffinactives]').val(inact);

  console.log('submit:', $('input').val();

  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Then you should see 'submit: link1' in your console when you submit the form.